# Расположить элементы в столбец

Tags: css, css3

Нужно расположить 2 diva (один из которых пустой) в 1 колонку, используя flex, и указывая ширину\высоту в %. Т.е чтоб это было адаптивным. Можно ли это сделать на flex? Или только на grid?

В итоге должно получиться

[image: картинка]

```css
.container{
display:flex;
}

.a{
width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.b{
width:100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget sodales neque, quis blandit risus. Etiam ultrices convallis ipsum a viverra. In est felis, dapibus sit amet est in, aliquet ullamcorper urna.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы расположить два блока друг под другом через Flexbox, достаточно для родителя указать `flex-direction: column`.

Но вот задать высоту дочерних элементов в процентах не получится.

В CSS существуют проблемы с определением высоты элемента относительно родителя в процентах, так как Вы загоняете алгоритм отрисовки в цикличность и тупик.

Ведь высота родительского блока заранее неизвестна и определяется суммарной высотой содержимого. Но одновременно с этим, Вы хотите, чтобы высота содержимого определялась как половина от высоты родителя (которая заранее неизвестна). Нет точки отсчёта

Comment: Каким образом тогда адаптивно расположить 2 этих элемента, не задавая явных размеров пустому элементу div? 
Через grid оба этих контейнера все равно имеют разную высоту.

Comment: Обычные два блока и так располагаются друг под другом и занимают всю ширину родителя. Тут дополнительная адаптивность не нужна. Если нельзя задавать фиксированных размеров дочернему элементу, тогда нужно задавать размеры родителю и уже тогда в процентах размеры дочернему элементу.